# Filtering objects by nested list property value

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, asp.net-core

I have a data grid with a column (`Quantity`) that is bound to a nested list `int` type property as follows:

```
data.PackageData.Contents.FirstOrDefault().orderedQuantity
```

When user apply a filter object (`FilterValue`) to that column I have to filter data using `IQueryable` query. What I have tried was something like this.

```
query = query.Where(e => e.PackageData.Contents.FirstOrDefault().orderedQuantity.Equals((Int16)FilterValue))
```

but when I trying to fetch data, I get an error.

```
data = query.ToList();
```

> The LINQ expression 'DbSet().Where(p => (int)EF.Property<List>(EF.Property(p, "PackageData"), "Contents").AsQueryable().Select(o => (int?)o.orderedQuantity).FirstOrDefault().Equals((int)__p_0))' could not be translated.

How can I achieve this using LINQ?

**Update**

I tried with following LINQ. but still I get an error.

```
var filteredQty = (Int16)filter.FilterValue;
query = query.Where(e => e.PackageData.Contents.Any(i => i.orderedQuantity.Equals(filteredQty)));
```

Comment: you don't use the `Where` corrctly, this may be something more like `.Where(e => e.PackageData.Contents.OrderedQuantity == (Int16)FilterValue)`. In fact, `Where() returns the list of items that answers to the condition `OrderedQuantity = (Int16)FilterValue)`, the `FirstOrDefault` returns the first item that answers to this condition, so `Where` and `FirstAndDefault` don't go together.

Comment: You need to separate the `FirstOrDefault` and filtering - first do `Where` then do `FirstOrDefault`. C# is a language of types, without knowing the types involved (what is `Contents`? How does it relate to filtering data?) it is hard to be more specific.

Comment: `Contents` is a type of `List<PackageContent>` and `OrderedQuantity` is a property of `PackageContent`. According to the requirement I have to bind grid column to `OrderedQuantity` of first element on `Contents` list.

Comment: Why do you use `Equals`? Last query looks correct, but remove `Equals`.

Answer (score 0):

Try to create external variable, as:

```cs
var filterValueInt = (short)FilterValue;

var query = query.Where(e => e.PackageData.Contents
      .FirstOrDefault().orderedQuantity == filterValueInt);
```

EF try to translate to SQL. In the simplest cases, as example:

LINQ:

```cs
        var myUsers = Users
            .Where(user => user.Id >= 5)
            .Select(user => user.Name)
            .ToList();
```

SQL:

```sql
  SELECT Name FROM Users WHERE Id >= 5;
```

(The result in SQL is more complex than that in reality but that's the idea)

When EF won't be able to translate to SQL, I think there's no choice left but to go through IEnumerable (to run LINQ in memory)

```cs
    var list = query.ToList()
    
    var filterValueInt = (short)FilterValue;

    list = list.Where(e => e.PackageData.Contents
        .FirstOrDefault().orderedQuantity == filterValueInt)`
        .ToList()
```

Comment: But I'm trying to achieve server-side pagination. So, I can't use `ToList()` until I apply all filers on the grid to the `query`.